# Как отловить отмену шаринга при использовании дефолтного android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent

Задача: показать кастомное сообщение "Shared!" если юзер поделился инфой.

Суть проблемы:

1. Юзер выбирает приложение в котором хочет поделиться инфой
2. после выбора переходит в приложение которое выбрал
3. здесь он внезапно передумал и отменил шаринг

Вопрос - как мне предусмотреть это поведение и отловить отмену шаринга? Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это возможно только если шаринг происходит через SDK к-л сервиса (VK, например) и его авторы предусмотрели такую возможность и предоставили соответствующий способ. Во всех остальных случаях вы не можете узнать что сделал юзер в другом приложении.

Comment: Но система же мне как то высвечивает дефолтный попап когда я все же пошарил инфу(message sent) и наоборот при отмене ничего не происходит. получается приложение как то все же информируется об результате шаринг ивента.

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii, вот аналог на англ - [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8794115/3212712). Кратко - вы можете вызывать `startActivityForResult()` и молить богов о том, что хоть что-то полезное придёт обратно в метод `onActivityResult()`. А придёт или нет - полностью зависит от разработчиков приложения, кое схватило `Intent`

Comment: Спасибо, после долгого анализа, пришел к тому что без кастомного шаринка это действительно невозможно, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
startActivityForResult(shareIntent, shareRequestCode);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == shareRequestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //показывать кастомное сообщение
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению resultCode = 0 и когда я пошарил и когда отменил шарин:(